# How to prevent fragmentation in Java?

Tags: java, performance

I have an interview and I was ask how to prevent Memory Fragmentation in Java. Can Anyone summarize how Java deal with it ? I've read some documents but it very complicated.

Comment: How is this title related to your question?

Comment: You don't do anything. The JVM does it. Too broad.

Comment: @EJP. I already knew this. I'm trying to understand how Java did to prevent memory fragment. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: you use a generational garbage collector.

Except that most modern Java implementations<sup>1</sup> use a generational collector *by default*.  In other words, you (the programmer) don't need to deal with the problem because it is already dealt with.

The only situation where you might run into fragmentation is if you have mis-tuned the low-pause collector and it has fallen back to doing a "stop the world" full collection.  At that point, you might be using a non-compacting collector, and fragmentation might ensue.  But the solution there is to adjust the tuning (or the application, or the heap size) to avoid getting into that situation.

If you want more information about garbage collectors work, there are whole textbooks on the subject.  And the various Java collectors are covered in depth in various articles and published research papers.

> I've read some documents but it very complicated.

Yes, it is.  It is hard work becoming an expert.

---

<sup>1 - Some really old Java implementations used primitive mark-sweep collectors.  But they are long gone.</sup>